# Combinatorics of a straight hand (poker)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

Quoting the book I'm reading:

> A poker hand consists of 5 cards. If the cards have distinct consecutive values and
>   are not all of the same suits, we say that the hand is a straight. For instance, a hand
>   consisting of the five of spades, six of spades, seven of spades, eight of spades, and
>   nine of hearts is a straight. What is the probability that one is dealt a straight?

The book gives a solution to this problem, but I don't quite agree with the combinatorics of it. It starts calculating how many poker hands there are, it argues that there are $52\choose 5$, which I totally agree since a hand is to choose 5 cards in 52 where the order doesn't matter, so it's not $52\times51\times50\times49\times48$. Now for the part I don't agree, after it the book reads:

> To determine the number of outcomes that are straights, let us first determine
>   the number of possible outcomes for which the poker hand consists of an ace, two,
>   three, four, and five (the suits being irrelevant). Since the ace can be any 1 of the 4
>   possible aces, and similarly for the two, three, four, and five, it follows that there are
>   $4^5$ outcomes leading to exactly one ace, two, three, four, and five.

My question is since the order doesn't matter a hand like A-2-3-4-5 and A-4-3-5-2 are both straights and are the same hand, actually, all the $5!$ permutations of it are the same hand, so there should be (ignoring, for now, the suit) $(4^5)/5!$ unique straight hands that the lower card is an ace! Now, considering the suit, we have to subtract 4 hands, which the book does. Where is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: You didn't count anything more times. A simple way to see that your reasoning is wrong is that $4^5$ isn't divisible by $5!$, and there should be integer many straight hands. Maybe you could convince yourself with this: suppose you only get dealt 2 cards, and are considering "straights" consisting of ace and two. Can you list all 16 of them and convince yourself that you should not divide by $2!$? Try doing it with three cards as well.

Comment: The number of ways to get dealt A-2-3-4-5, in that order, is $4^5$.  The number of ways to get dealt A-4-3-5-2, in that order, is another $4^5$.  Since there are $5!$ orderings, the number of ways to get dealt an A-thru-5 straight, in any order, but counting different orderings as distinct, is $5! 4^5$.  If different orderings (of a given set of 5 cards) are considered non-distinct, you then have to divide by $5!$ to get $5! 4^5 / 5! = 4^5$.  Does this make sense?

Comment: A good way to help verify the (*in*)correctness of a formula is to try to apply it in extreme circumstances.  Supposing that your deck only consisted of five cards in the first place (*the ace through the five of spades for instance*) and you draw five cards and ask for the probability of your hand being a straight-flush, your proposed solution applied to this scenario would have you think it is a non-zero chance of failure when it should be obvious that you wind up with the same hand in every situation and that hand is indeed a straight-flush.

Comment: It doesn't matter in what order the five cards of a hand are dealt, but of course you can give each card a value (a number from 1 to 52) and order your five cards by value, which makes it easier to distinguish the different hands. Just don't mix up these two "orders".

Comment: Really liked Antkam reasoning. I also noted that I can think of getting a hand like ace to five as 5 experiments, each one I choose 1 card in 4 possibilities (1 of 4 aces, after 1 of 4 two, etc), so it would be $4\choose1$ $\times5 = 4^5$, reasoning like that I totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to look at permutations. You can do combinatorics directly on the straight sequences.

Order the card ranks A, K, $\cdots$, 3, 2, A. The ace appears twice, because of its double function as the highest and lowest rank in a straight.

It's easy to see that there are 10 straights possible that way: A through T, K through 9, ..., 5 through A.

And there are $4 \choose 1$ ways suits can be chosen each card, so there are $10 \times 4^5$ ways of drawing such a straight sequence. However, we still need to take off the number of cases where all suits are the same, which would make it a straight flush, not a straight. This is easy: for each suit there are 10 straight flushes. Putting things together,
$$
\# \textrm{straights} = 10 \times 4^5 - 40 = 10200
$$
The total number of 5-card hands that can be dealt from a deck of 52 is $52 \choose 5$. So the probability of drawing a straight is
$$
P(\textrm{straight}) = \frac{10200}{52\choose 5} = 0.00392465 \approx 0.3925\%
$$